# onplay and onplaying difference?

Tags: javascript, attributes, dom-events

I want to know the difference between `onplay` and `onplaying` events.

I've looked at the examples in the W3C, but I could not find any differences.
(https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html)

Help me!

Answer (score 1):

They might sound similar but are fired in different conditions.

The [W3C Media Elements event summary](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics-embedded-content.html#media-elements-event-summary) gives pretty good definitions of the events, and regarding your question:

- The `play` event is simple, and is fired when video starts due to `autoplay` attribute being `true`, or if the `play()` method has returned, and only when `paused` was true.
- The `playing` event is a bit more tricky. It is fired if `paused` was true, but also on different cases depending on the element state. These cases are well defined, but remain obscure without an example.

Hopefully, the link you provided actually shows these differences, and if you use the seek bar a couple of times, you will see that the `playing` event is called whereas the `play` event isn't.

Answer (score 1):

The [`play`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics-embedded-content.html#eventdef-media-play) event indicates that the media element is started or restarted see: [`play() and pause()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics-embedded-content.html#playing-the-media-resource), think of the media element as being in "playback mode" (*where "playback mode" is my term and not a term found in the specifications*).

The [`playing`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics-embedded-content.html#eventdef-media-playing) and [`waiting`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics-embedded-content.html#eventdef-media-waiting) events may alternate while the media element is in "playback mode" as the source is buffered.